# 301 redirect incoming broken links to home using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have few domains which have good seo ranking. My problem is that there are few back links for my domains on internet which are broken. I want to 301 redirect those broken links to home page of my website with the help of .htaccess file.

I am using below code to do this purpose.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

But above code is  messing the css,js and images request of the website. I just want the incoming broken links to get redirected.

What will be correct way to do so?

Comment: How are they messing up the css/js?

Comment: If that broken urls have extention, for example, html, you may add Cond